# Como Migrar Banco SQL Server para Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Criei um diagrama no [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), onde ele cria automaticamente toda a estrutura do banco, só que terei que migrar para o Oracle.

Eu consigo migrar toda a estrutura (tabelas, FKs, PKs, etc.) com alguma ferramenta?

Obs. 1: Não existem dados ainda nas tabelas.

Obs. 2: Estou usando [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) e o [oracle-11g](/questions/tagged/oracle-11g).

Comment: Você está preocupado, no momento, em migrar somente o banco, correto (de SQL Server p/ Oracle)? Ou seja, levar objetos de um lado para o outro. Aplicações que utilizam o SQL Server e que irão utilizar o Oracle fazem parte dessa migração?

Comment: Existe também outras ferramentas que faz esse serviço como por exemplo o fullcopyconvert.

Comment: Apesar do post ser um pouco antigo vou deixar minha contribuição. Existe o FullCopyConvert, segue o link para download. [www.fullcopyconvert.com.br/download](http://www.fullcopyconvert.com.br/download)

Answer (score 2):

Existe o ***Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle*** que pode lhe ajudar.
Ele faz uma lista com os objetos que podem ser migrados nativamente e possíveis erros.
Alguns itens como objetos criptografados ele não executa a leitura.

Answer (score 0):

A Oracle possui um guia de migração com vídeos e instruções textuais onde todos os passos para a migração estão explicados:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html